# jquerymobile generic photopopup

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, photo-gallery

I'm new at javascript and would like to adapt the following jquerymobile code to allow it to be used without hardcoding the image path in the data-role="popup" div.

Here are the two parts to the code. The first section is used to display a thumbnail that when touched displays a lightbox with a higher res picture:

```
<a href="#popupPhoto" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-inline="true" data-transition="fade" ><img  class="v100col" alt="equinox" src="images/equinox.jpg"></a>
```

Touching the picture executes the following to display the popup:

```
</div>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupPhoto" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" data-corners="false">
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a><img class="popphoto" rc="images/equinox_big.jpg" alt="Equinox">
</div>
```

I would like to replace  src="images/equinox_big.jpg" with a variable so that the same div routine can be executed for all the images on my mobile page.

Before the image is displayed the following on-event function executes

```
$( ".photopopup" ).on({
popupbeforeposition: function() {
var maxHeight = $( window ).height() - 60 + "px";
$( ".photopopup img" ).css( "max-height", maxHeight );
}
});
```

Can this be done by modifying the popupbeforeposition js function or by some other method?

Thanks
Elliot``

Answer (score 1):

Just because I am more server-side developer, I would do a database query with mysql and retrieve the image names with php.

Something like:

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $img = $row['img_name'];
    echo '<img src="'.$img.'"/>';
}
?>
```

I think this may be the best solution if you want to manage a large number of images and to have them nicely organized in a database.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think the page is refreshed on the server between when the the thumbnail is touched and when the full image displays. So it doesn't seem to me that php would be the way to go. I would think that if it's possible the popupbeforeposition would have to have access to

Comment: it works and querys the page normally, just check this test site by me http://test.slimspa.eu/andrea/mobile/